# What is better, LASSO or AIC for model selection?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, model-selection, lasso, aic

I am confused. Assume we are dealing with a linear model which has around 50 covariates. Then, even though it is already quite computationally intense, we can still use AIC to perform model selection. Then should we go for LASSO in this case?

Comment: Lasso is an estimation technique, while AIC is "an estimator of the relative quality of statistical models for a given set of data" (quoting Wikipedia). Thus you are comparing apples to oranges. For example, you can use AIC to evaluate a model fit by Lasso.

Comment: Yes, or in other words: LASSO can be understood as performing "variable selection" *within* a given model (because it will drive most coefficients to be near 0, leaving only a few variables to meaningfully contribute to the model), whereas AIC is used to do model selection.

Comment: +1 for @RichardHardy and Ruben van Bergen. However, even though both of you are technically correct, there are feature selection *strategies* based on selecting the combination of features from a set of features which has the lowest AIC (regardless of whether you would assume this technique flawed, it does exist). This strategy could be compared with using LASSO to select features from the same set. The question is, on what grounds are we comparing these techniques (computational requirements, external validity, etc.)?

Comment: @IWS, your formulation should help the OP improve his/her question. +1.